# Given nontrivial examples of continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int^{a+1}_{a} f(t)dt=1$ for all $a\in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Given nontrivial examples of continuous functions $f:  \mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ satisfying $\int^{a+1}_{a} f(t)dt=1$ for all $a\in \mathbb {R}$. Can you give a complete description of all such functions, giving all solutions for $f$?

Here is my attempt:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{a}^{a+1}f(x) \,dx\right) = \frac{d}{dx} (1)  \rightarrow   f(x)\Bigg|^{a+1}_a = 0 \rightarrow f(a+1) = f(a)$$

This shows that $f(x)$ is a periodic function.

Comment: Please add your attempt in the body of your question as comments are both less viewable and more easily deleted.

Comment: I can sympathise with your LaTeX struggle. Have an upvote. Just a friendly tip for the future though; sometimes it's better to use more words and less symbols. Phrases like "therefore", "which means that", "implies that", "then", "thus", and "so" are often preferable to implication arrows which can produce overly dense formulas that are hard on the eyes. Your professors will appreciate it.

Comment: D.w.r. t $a$ not $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with your notation - $\int_a^{a+1} f(x) dx$ is not a function of $x$ (the $x$ inside the integral is a "bound variable" and cannot be manipulated outside of it).

Your general answer is correct. To fix the notation problem, we might instead write $\frac{d}{da} \int_a^{a+1} f(x) dx = f(a+1) \frac{d}{da}(a+1) - f(a) \frac{d}{da}(a) = f(a+1) - f(a)$. Then you can note that $f(a+1) - f(a) = \frac{d}{da} (1) = 0$, implying that $f(a+1) = f(a)$, and hence $f$ has period 1.

However, that does not completely describe all such functions, because, for example, $\sin (2 \pi x)$ is 1-periodic but does not satisfy the integral constraint.

With that said, the complete family of functions is still pretty broad. You can show that if $f$ is 1-periodic then the given integral constraint is equivalent to $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$. From there, you can possibly define a less restricted function $g(x)$ and describe a way to construct $f(x)$ from $g(x)$.

Comment: You can take **any** continuous function on $[01]$ with $f(0)=f(1)$ and $\int_0^{1} f(x)dx=1$ and then extend this to the whole real line by periodicity. This is a complete description of all solutions.

Comment: Yep, that is true and was part of what I was getting at in my last sentence. You can go even further by taking any $g(x)$ with non-zero integral on $[0,1]$ and scaling, depending on how fancy you want to get.